# Using figure labels without showing the figures.

Tags: floats, labels

I am trying to have two separate documents: one that contains text and another one that contains figures. 
However, I still want to reference the Figures from the second document in the text document.

I thought it would be possible just to have the figure label in the text, without including graphics (like below). But this doesn't work, the counting gets all messed up.

```
\begin{figure}
%\includegraphics[width= .7\textwidth]{Figures/Figure1.pdf}
\label{fig:figure1}
\end{figure}
```

Any idea how to do this?

Thank you, 
best,

Ana

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You have no `\caption` in your `figure` environment --> there's no figure numbering then

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But I don't have a caption, because I don't want to have the Figure or the caption of the figure anywhere in the first document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\usepackage{xr}` and the `\externaldocument` command to grab the references from that file. I named the other document `onlyfigures.tex`.

In order to prevent messing up the label names, you can decide that the references of the external file get a prefix, say `extfig-`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xr}


\externaldocument[extfig-]{onlyfigures}

\begin{document}

\section{The document without figure}

In \ref{extfig-fig:one} we see that 

\end{document}
```

Here is `onlyfigures.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}

\caption{A figure}\label{fig:one}

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```